# Relay to control the power rail on a PCI adapter

Tags: relay, 12v

I am trying to find a relay which will control the 12V power rail of a PCIe adapter so I can cycle power to a device during testing.  The relay should be normally closed.  I plan to control the relay using a GPIO from a Raspberry Pi so the signal should be 3.3V.  I have tried looking digikey and narrowing down the search criteria, but I can't seem to find one.  If one doesn't exist, what would it take to create a switch using components (i.e., MOSFETs).  Thanks.

Comment: look for SSR ( Solid state relay), should be plenty that can do this, and quite small. They are just integrated MOSFET switches with a bunch of protection included.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi GPIO is not powerful enough to directly drive a relay. You will need to add a transistor to do that. Google for circuit solutions because there are plenty examples of this to be found.

Comment: Close.  Google 3.3V coil relay.

Comment: I don't see how this question is off topic.  I asked a specific question to the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

A solid state relay rated for mains voltage will use a triac internally, so it will drop 2V, won't work for your 12V application. Also it is likely not to turn on at all.

Just use a PMOS as a high side switch. Pick a PMOS with proper RdsON rating according to your current for low voltage drop, and GND needs to be connected on both sides of course. Schematic example:

[image]

Or you can use a high side switch like [this one](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/1e/52/ef/e0/cc/90/4e/2e/CD00240716.pdf/files/CD00240716.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00240716.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I would use an N channel MOSFET connected as shown and a relay with a coil rating of 12 volt. +Vdd will be the 12 volt connection. Vcc will be your 3.3 volt logic supply.

Choose a MOSFET that has low enough gate threshold voltage to suit your 3.3 volt logic signals. A \$V_{GS(Threshold)}\$ of under 2 volts should be sufficient.

If the logic level is 1 then the relay activates and open circuits the normally closed contact.